# How can I programmatically open the tooltip of a leaflet marker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am using leaflet and I have a few markers. If I hover on the marker icon its tooltip automatically opens, showing the related data. I have my markers stored inside a variable called `woMarkers` and everything works using it except this feature. If I do something like this:

```
$(woMarkers[0]._icon).hover();
```

then nothing happens, no error and the tooltip does not open. These are the options I am using:

```
        var woOptions = {
            fitBounds: true,
            enableLandmarkLink: false,
            reDrawBounds: true,
            showControls: true,
            getName: function(record) {
                return record[('Job Number' in record ? 'Job Number' : 'Name')];
            },
            markerIconTemplate: '<div class="fi-marker-container %6" data-workorder="%3"><a class="icon" style="color: %4;">%1%2</a></div><div class="fi-marker-pointer-container"><div class="fi-marker-pointer %6"></div></div>',
            markerSelection: true,
            displayLabels: mapLabels,
            additionalMarkerMarkup: {
                column: 'Status', /* Display additional Marker html pending on a column value */
                values: {
                    '1': '<img class="top-right-icon" src="/Images/Icons/Help.png" />',
                    '2': '<img class="top-right-icon" src="/Images/Icons/CheckCircle.png" />',
                    '3': '<img class="top-right-icon" src="/Images/Icons/CheckCircle.png" />',
                    '4': '<img class="top-right-icon" src="/Images/Icons/CheckCircle.png" />',
                    '5': '<img class="top-right-icon" src="/Images/Icons/Warning.png" />'
                },
                columns: ["Workorder #"]
            },
            layer: new L.LayerGroup()
        };
```

So, my question is as follows: If I have a marker object, how can I programmatically open its tooltip?

Comment: For the tooltip, do you use Leaflet.label plugin or Leaflet 1.0 built-in `L.tooltip` / `marker.bindTooltip`?

Comment: @ghybs, I do not know. How can I check which one is used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use `marker.fire("mouseover")`, using Leaflet [built-in event management methods](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#evented-fire).

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/92/

Comment: That is the solution! Thank you, will accept it when I can.

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using the Leaflet Tooltip, you can open it by calling:

```
marker.openTooltip();
```

See [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tooltip).

Comment: .openTooltip is undefined

Comment: No, how should I use that?

Comment: To open a popup you can use `.openPopup()`.

Comment: If it is undefined you are likely trying to call it on the marker image rather than the leaflet object.